# how to determine byte and value of keyboard key in Python

Tags: python, logging, keyboard, byte, x11

Using [the code of PyKeylogger](https://github.com/amoffat/pykeylogger/blob/master/keylogger.py) (which uses Xlib), I can detect the use of most keyboard keys, but I am having difficulty detecting the up arrow key. Lines such as the following could be added to the keyboard map to detect most or the arrow keys:

```
14: {
    0b00000001: ("<pageup>", "shift-pageup"),
    0b00000010: ("<left>", "shift-left"),
    0b00000100: ("<right>", "shift-right"),
    0b00001000: ("<end>", "shift-end"),
    0b00010000: ("<down>", "shift-down"),
    0b00100000: ("<pagedown>", "shift-PgDn"),
    0b01000000: ("<insert>", "shift-insert")
},
```

How can I detect the up arrow key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up arrow

```
13: {
    0b10000000: ("<up>", "shift-up")
},
```

---

I got PyKeylogger source code and I found place where I could get code for any key.

See `print i, o` in code below.  It gave me `13 128` (`13 0b10000000`) for up arrow

```
# aggregate the pressed keys
pressed = []
for i, k in enumerate(keypresses_raw):
    o = ord(k)
    if o:
        #print i, o # this line print code for any pressed key
        for byte,key in key_mapping.get(i, {}).iteritems():
            if byte & o:
                if isinstance(key, tuple): key = key[shift or caps_lock_state]
                pressed.append(key)
```

Comment: With `print i, o` you can find another codes if you will need it.